# 400 Error while importing csv file from bucket storage using Cloud SQL Admin API in C# .NET

Tags: c#, google-cloud-sql, google-apis-explorer

I am using the Google.Apis.SQLAdmin.v1beta4 in .NET client library for importing the SQL dump or CSV file from Cloud Storage into Cloud SQL instance. I am getting the error 400 with following message

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Unknown export file type.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Unknown export file type.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "errorExportUnknownFileType"
}
]
}
}

Unknown export file type with 400 status code

I tried this again after providing the access to the service account of storage admin, but no joy.

I have used the blow C# provided in the sample code

```
SQLAdminService sqlAdminService = new SQLAdminService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
    ApplicationName = "Google-SQLAdminSample/0.1",
});

// Project ID of the project that contains the instance.
string project = "projectName";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

// Cloud SQL instance ID. This does not include the project ID.
string instance = "cloudinstance";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

// TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
Data.InstancesImportRequest requestBody = new Data.InstancesImportRequest
{
    ImportContext = new Data.ImportContext
    {
        Uri = @"gs://TableName/TableName.csv",
        Database = "DB NAME",
        Kind= "sql#importContext",
        FileType = "CSV",
        CsvImportOptions =  new Data.ImportContext.CsvImportOptionsData
        {
            Table= "TableName"
        }
    }
};

InstancesResource.ImportRequest request = sqlAdminService.Instances.Import(requestBody, project, instance);

Data.Operation response = request.Execute();

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
```

Can you help me with this error.
Note : - The table I am importing is already created into cloud sql server

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: The line of code which throws exception is 
Data.Operation response = request.Execute();

Comment: Please edit your question with the `exact` error. The error indicates an export error for an import operation. Also, show the actual project and strings.

Comment: Here is the actual error 

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unknown export file type.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown export file type.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "errorExportUnknownFileType"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I noticed you are a new user. Are you having difficulty editing your question to include information? Details should go into the question.

Comment: I can't enter the google cloud project details here after having a word with my seniors. So, is it possible to help without the details being entered